# Writing input into separate arrays and an output file

Tags: c++

The code inputs an `int`, `n`, which is the number of lines to follow. Then, on each line, the first number goes to array `A`, the second to `B`, and the third to `C`. I then pass these 4 arguments to `sub` which I have no control over (in an object file where I don't know the implementation). All I know is that it returns an `int`.

What I do then is write `n`, the three arrays, and the result of `sub` into an output file. Pretty simple code.

This code works as expected, but I just want to see if there are any conventions I should be following (especially C++11) and ideas to consider for efficiency.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "sub.h"

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(...);

    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    int n;
    std::string firstLine;
    getline(file, firstLine);
    std::stringstream(firstLine) >> n;
    
    int a,b,c;
    std::vector<int> A1,B1,C1;
    while (file >> a >> b >> c) {
        A1.push_back(a);
        B1.push_back(b);
        C1.push_back(c);
    }
    
    file.close();
    
    std::ofstream output;
    output.open(...);

    output << n << "\n";
    
    size_t size = A1.size();
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        output << A1[i] << " " << B1[i] << " " << C1[i] << std::endl;
    }
    
    //call sub method with pointer to beginning of vectors
    //I have no control over sub method, its signature is (int, int*, int*, int*)
    int n1 = sub(n, &A1[0], &B1[0], &C1[0]);
    
    //output result and close file
    output << n1;
    output.close();
}
```

Example input:

> 0 1 2 <- This is A[0], B[0], C[0]
>
> 2 3 4 <- This is A[1], B[1], C[1]
>
> 4 5 6 <- This is A[2], B[2], C[2]

The range-based `for`-loop would not work in this case. It would, however, if I printed all of A, B, or C on one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It's a good idea to order your STL `#include`s either alphabetically or by groups (see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30261/code-logicistic-and-cleanliness/30264#30264) answer for more details).  Header files should also precede STL `#include`s to avoid dependencies.
- I'd give your IO files more accurate names (such as `inFile` and `outFile`).
- Include `<cstdlib>` for `EXIT_FAILURE`.
- This is C++ and not C, so use `std::size_t` instead of `size_t`.
- Put the `std::vector` declarations (`A1`, `B1`, `C1`) on separate lines.
- You don't have to create another size variable for `A1.size()` just for a loop.

  In that same loop: you're looping through all three arrays at once, but are using one vector's size to do that.  That's a bad idea.  If they happen to be different sizes, you're going to run into problems.
- This:

  ```
  int n1 = sub(n, &A1[0], &B1[0], &C1[0]);
  ```

  is best written as this (with iterators):

  ```
  int n1 = sub(n, A1.begin(), B1.begin(), C1.begin());
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The reason I cannot do the range-based for loop is that I need to print in the same order as I input. I'll edit my question with an example.

Comment: Oh, okay.  Again, just make sure you're always keeping alert of going out of bounds in any situation.

Comment: Thanks. I originally had `A.at(i)` because it had bounds checking. However, I decided against it due to a suggestion I've seen before about how `operator[]()` is faster than `.at()`.

Comment: Right.  `at()` is best if you *may* go out of bounds and/or if you need to throw exceptions.

Comment: No problem!  Feel free to vote on this once you've earned enough rep.  I may still add to this answer if I find anything else.